# In Excel, how to add serial number to only unique values in a column and let the duplicate values have same serial number as the original one?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, filtered

I am trying to add a serial number to the rows in an excel sheet. I have multiple duplicate values in "ID" column and I am hiding the duplicate values first and then trying to add the serial number only for the unique values. I want all the duplicate values to have same serial number as the original value.

My sheet looks like this now : [image: Original sheet]

It looks like this after hiding the duplicates: [image: Duplicates hidden]

What I am trying to achieve looks like this: [image: Expected]

There are more than 50K rows and I am hoping that there is some way to do this in excel without manually filling in the numbers in the "No." column.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look Here: [Assign serial number to unique value with Formula](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4211-excel-assign-number-to-duplicates.html)

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya: your proposal will yield "1,2,1,2,1,2,3" while the author wants "1,1,2,2,3,3,3".

Comment: Nope it works for me. Instead of `VLOOKUP()` using `XLOOKUP()` `=IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B2,B2)=1,MAX(A$1:A1)+1,XLOOKUP(B2,B$1:B1,A$1:A1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a simple formula:

```
=IF(B2=B3,A2,A2+1)
```

First put the value "1" in cell "A2". Then put the mentioned value below and continue dragging and dropping.

Your result will look as follows:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That works if sorted only. A simple `=match(b2,b:b,0)` would do (returning the row number of the first found row with that value)

Comment: @P.b: this, however, does not result in values 1, 2, 3.

Comment: True, but the 1, 2, 3 was for explaining (I think).

Comment: Else check answer from @Vbasic2008

Comment: @Dominique Your suggestion worked like a charm in my scenario as all the values are sorted. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

### Add Sequential Serial Numbers

- In cell `A2` (adjust the last row):

```
=XMATCH(B2:B13,UNIQUE(B2:B13))
```

[image]